# HTML form not sending parameters

Tags: forms, html

I wrote a login panel for my website and everything looks fine but when I click on submit page refreshes and no parameters are being sent. I checked both get andpost methods but it's not working. here is my code:

```
<form id="login_form" action="index.php?task=login" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input class="span2" id="username" type="text" value="Username" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Username'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username') this.value='';">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-cog"></i></span>
                <input class="span2" id="password" type="password" value="Password" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Password'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Password') this.value='';" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your input tags don't have the `name` attribute which is required to post the value.

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

Comment: I was having the same issue using Boot Strap login form elements (type="email", type="password"). This answer is a saviour !

Comment: Old but gold!  Thank you so much.